# Receive POST information from callback, Android WebView

Tags: android, webview

My scenario is this: we point the user to a form where they fill in the data (3DSecure) and then POST, the website then POSTS the response to a callback URL - this response is what I want to capture. `WebView.shouldInterceptRequest()` can get the headers but not the content (Why, Google?). I tried [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613798/is-it-possible-to-access-html-form-data-posted-through-a-webview) and it can get the POST data that the user sends. Is there any way to use Javascript to catch the POST data being received to a callback of my choosing?

I saw [this post from 5 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958596/receive-post-data-from-a-3rd-party-within-a-webview) and the man resorted to POSTing the response back to a server and then getting the contents from the phone. This is far from ideal. Surely there's a newer solution?

`shouldInterceptRequest()` mentions that a response contains the "[response information or null if the WebView should load the resource itself](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldInterceptRequest)", how do I get it so that the WebView shouldn't load the resource itself? The source code seems to return null always.

Comment: `Is there any way to use Javascript to catch the POST data`. Yes. There is. You can use practically the same javascript as you would use for form input validation before the actual post is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this gentleman's library: https://github.com/LivotovLabs/3DSView

If one was looking to do this with something other than 3DSecure they could use it as a template.